# Error on gcloud app deployment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gcloud

I am trying to use gcloud in order to deploy a nodejs app. I have followed this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/deploy-mongodb).

When I run:

```
gcloud preview app deploy
```

I have 2 possible issue:

First :

> Beginning deployment... If this is your first deployment, this may
>   take a while...failed. ERROR: gcloud crashed (ResponseNotReady)

Or sometimes the process go further :

> Verifying that Managed VMs are enabled and ready. ERROR: gcloud
>   crashed (ResponseNotReady)

The log look like that :

> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin..\lib\third_party\httplib2__init__.py",
>   line 1308, in _conn_request
>       response = conn.getresponse()
>
> File "C:\python27_x64\lib\httplib.py", line 1119, in getresponse
>       raise ResponseNotReady() ResponseNotReady 2016-02-22 15:13:00,937 ERROR    root            gcloud crashed (ResponseNotReady):

Thank you !

Comment: It looks like you're on either a shaky network connection, or behind a firewall/proxy that isn't letting traffic through. `ResponseNotReady` here indicates network issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be some connection instability... I made it without any change but retrying like an hundred times.